# unable to connect local host to flutter using http

Tags: sql-server, flutter, asp.net-core, http

I am trying to connect the local host database to flutter. I used asp.net core Web API to get the data to the local host web. This is how the information is displayed.

[information in local host along with url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4his.png)

I tried referring how to call data from a live server https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#1-add-the-http-package and this worked. When I tried changing to local however, it eventually stops working with a connection time out. For reference this is how the code looks like:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Employee> fetchEmployee() async {
  final response = await http
      .get(Uri.parse('https://192.168.156.1:7040/api/Employees/GetAllEmployees/2'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Employee.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class Employee {
  final int Id;
  final String l_name;
  final String f_name;

  const Employee({
    required this.Id,
    required this.l_name,
    required this.f_name,
  });

  factory Employee.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Employee(
      Id: json['Id'],
      l_name: json['l_name'],
      f_name: json['f_name'],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future<Employee> futureAlbum;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureAlbum = fetchEmployee();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<Employee>(
            future: futureAlbum,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data!.f_name);
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('${snapshot.error}');
              }

              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I read somewhere if I try passing uri as http://localhost:7040/ it wont work and also it refuses connection so I am using the laptop's IP address. I also made sure the emulator's IP address matches the ip address I inserted. Does anyone know why this is happening and any suggestions to fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is running on localhost and you are testing your app on an Android emulator & then replace the below-mentioned things.

```
http://localhost:3000
```

with

```
http://10.0.2.2:3000
```

Comment: do you mean in the website url or in flutter?

Comment: If you're using a local server, then instead of using http://localhost:<port>, use http://10.0.2.2:<port>. 

It will only work on an Android emulator.

Comment: i am using the ip. but didn't work.